# Laravel 5: no foreign key when saving related models

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a simple one-to-one relationship between a User and a Profile, I'm trying to create a user and save their profile with the foreign key in one go and avoid having to pass the primary key and do two `save()` calls.

Laravel will try to insert the corresponding Profile values without the id pointing back to the user. What am I doing wrong ?

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }
}


class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_profile';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}

class UserController extends Controller
{

  public function create(Request $request)
  {

    $this->validate($request, [
    ...
    ]) ;

    $user = new User() ;
    $profile = new Profile() ;

    $user->name = $request->input('name') ; 
    ...

    $profile->first_name = $request->input('first_name') ;
    $profile->last_name = $request->input('last_name') ;
    ...

    $user->profile()->save($profile) ;
    // $profile->user()->save($user) ; // doesn't work

    // $profile->user()->associate($user) ; // doesn't work
    // $profile->save() ;    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need first to save the user

```
$user = new User;

$user->name = $request->input('name') ; 

$user->save();

$profile = new Profile;

$profile->first_name = $request->input('first_name') ;

$user->profile()->save($profile);
```

Comment: Well this is what I'm doing now, but I was looking for a way to save both in one call

Answer (score -2):

The function name you are looking is "associate"

```
$user->profile()->associate($profile);

$user->save();
```

Comment: I already tried that, moreover associate works with BelongsTo, not HasOne so it would have to be the other way around

Comment: @blackbird57 what error do you get? associate function udpates "Belongs To" Relationships so that should be correct. Do you run save after running the associate on user? $user->save(); ?